# Problem with random coordinate within range when close to earth limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coordinates

I'm creating a random point within the bounds of a map where the center is a geocoordinate I give.

```
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();    

var ptLat = Math.random() * (ne.lat() - sw.lat()) + sw.lat();
var ptLng = Math.random() * (ne.lng() - sw.lng()) + sw.lng();
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(ptLat,ptLng);
```

All works well in most cases but in the case of, for example, -7.47, 178.67 there will be problems as the bounds for the longitude will be 142, -142 and will mess up the random number since it can return values like 20,30 or 40 which are within the number range but not coordinate range.

What is the best option to calculate a random number for latitude or longitude within a range without messing it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LatLngBounds.toSpan](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds.toSpan)

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
var span = bounds.toSpan();
var ptLat = Math.random() * span.lat() + sw.lat();
var ptLng = Math.random() * span.lng() + sw.lng();
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(ptLat, ptLng);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/b846zo3h/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map with multiple random markers]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 64.197671,
    lng: -152.009373
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    createRandomMarker();
  });
}

function createRandomMarker() {
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
  var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var span = bounds.toSpan();
  console.log("span=" + span.toUrlValue(6) + "; sw=" + sw.toUrlValue(6) + " ne=" + ne.toUrlValue(6));
  var ptLat = Math.random() * span.lat() + sw.lat();
  var ptLng = Math.random() * span.lng() + sw.lng();
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(ptLat, ptLng);
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: map,
    title: 'Random point'
  });
  console.log("random marker at:" + marker2.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
  if (!bounds.contains(marker2.getPosition())) {
    alert("marker out of bounds:" + marker2.getPosition().toUrlValue());
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="createRandomMarker();" value="makeMarker" />
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```